# WPF nested list view in list item template

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

What I have here is a ListView that shows as an item another ListView with some more items.
So ill try to explain better.
For every lines of the ListViewMother I want a Listview linked to the datasource of lines.
So what i want to try later is to link the Page to a particular template given by a string called templatestyle that will be given to the ListviewMother to select the different ListStyle.
So my question is how to I link a datasource to a templated Listview?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
   Title = "MainWindow" Height = "350" Width = "604">

    <Grid>
        <ListView Name="ListviewMother">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Margin="20">
                        <TextBlock Text="aaaaaaa"></TextBlock>
                        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding lines}" Background="red"> (listitemson)
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid Margin="20" >
                                        <TextBox Text="aaaaaaaaaa" Margin="20"/>
                                        <TextBox Text="{Binding linenumber}" />
                                    </Grid>

                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

The c# code

```
namespace WpfApp2
{

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Page> pages = new ObservableCollection<Page>();
        public ObservableCollection<line> lines { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<line>();
        public MainWindow()

        {
            lines.Add(new line() { linenumber = "tsadssdest" });
            lines.Add(new line() { linenumber = "tedsfdsfdsst" });
            pages.Add(new Page() { Title = "asdsad"});
            pages.Add(new Page() { Title = "sdsadad"});
            pages.Add(new Page() { Title = "gggdfgs"});
            InitializeComponent();
            ListviewMother.ItemsSource = pages;



        }
    }
}
public class Page
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string TemplateStyle { get; set; }


}

public class line
{
    public string linenumber { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Are you going to show the same `lines` collection in each Page? Otherwise, `ObservableCollection<line> lines` should be a member of the Page class.

Comment: this works well but you must have a reference in Page to line.... I was thinking about a way to have this flexible. Because every template will every different binding names (line have linenumer... if I want to connect something else I really dont know how)

Comment: What does that mean? Do you want a single line collection, or one per Page? It can only be one or the other.

Comment: One per page. This is what blocks me.... How do you achieve that? How do you achieve a single line collection per page that is custom for every page? for example first page you have line the second one will be letters.... and all of this needs a reference into page! I try to do something dynamic.... Like every page already reference to a class without having a reference in Page.

Comment: Then the `lines` property should simply be a Page member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the collection of lines in your Page class.I do some modification for your code to show the ListView inside in ListView.

The xaml code is:

```
 <Grid>
    <ListView Name="ListviewMother">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Margin="20">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"></TextBlock>
                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding lines}" Background="red">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid Margin="2" >
                                    <TextBox Text="{Binding linenumber}" />
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

The cs code is:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Page> pages = new ObservableCollection<Page>();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        pages.Add(new Page() { Title = "Page1",lines=new ObservableCollection<line>() { new line() { linenumber="Line1_1"}, new line() { linenumber = "Line1_2" }, new line() { linenumber = "Line1_3" } } });
        pages.Add(new Page() { Title = "Page2",lines=new ObservableCollection<line>() { new line() { linenumber="Line2_1"}, new line() { linenumber = "Line2_2" }, new line() { linenumber = "Line2_3" } } });
        pages.Add(new Page() { Title = "Page3" });
        InitializeComponent();
        ListviewMother.ItemsSource = pages;
    }
}
public class Page
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string TemplateStyle { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<line> lines { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<line>();

}

public class line
{
    public string linenumber { get; set; }
}
```

The result picture is like this:
[image]